# Counting Polylines on top of one another in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I have a walking network, split into links.. Each link has more than one feature on top of each other which represents the number of times it was used within my network when plotting routes from destinations.

Is there a way I can merge each link back to one feature but with a field for the count on how many features were merged into one ?

Obviously this is one dataset, which over a 1,000 links so can I carry this out over the entire dataset... End result beings the network with a count field of the the number of time each link was used.

Comment: Try Find identical with Shape field, and then Summary statistics with count on FEAT_SEQ field. Then join this back to the original fc

Comment: Dissolve with no multipart. Assign unique id to segments. Spatial join to original, 1:M. Summarise Results by segment id. Transfer frequency to segments table, using attribute join.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help.... worked like a dream.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write a self-answer to let the community know some details about the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I did the following :

1. Delete Duplicates links from the network.
2. Gave each link on my network a unique ID
3. Saved as my network dataset
4. Took my routes dataset and did a summary statistics on Count and Unique ID and output a table
5. Joined this table back to my New network Dataset based on the unique ID.
6. Styled the line based on the count... here is the result - [image: demandonnetwork]

@BERA provided the advice.